# Javadoc Generation Problem in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javadoc, documentation-generation

I'm having a problem with the javadoc generation in eclipse. In advance, thanks for taking the time. Here's what happens: I go to `Project>Generate Javadoc...`, select all of the files in the project, then press finish.

Eclipse then goes and seemingly does its' thing. The output in the console looks more or less like this:

`Loading source files for package client...`

`Loading source files for package engine...`

`Constructing Javadoc information...`

`Standard Doclet version 1.6.0_16`

`Building tree for all the packages and classes...`

`Generating C:\...Tempus\API\client/\Tempus.html...`

Wait, what's that? "`/\`"??? That doesn't make any sense (or, at least, I don't think it does)! This "`/\`" pattern continues for all the classes in each package in my project. Later, the console window bar reads `<teminated> Javadoc Generation` instead of `Javadoc Generation` (which I'm assuming is bad) right after generating the `stylesheet.css`. The javadoc files are not generated, and I'm left with no outright evidence of an error. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's in the "Destination" field of your "Javadoc Generation" dialog (window you get when you click Project>Generate Javadoc...)?

Does it look like this?

```
C:\...Tempus\API\client/
```

If so, try removing the trailing slash.

Comment: Sorry, no dice. The destination field looks like this: `C:\...Tempus\API`

Comment: Yeah, after typing my response I looked closer and noticed I was getting some of the "/\" business in my paths as well... though it's working for me.

Comment: Found out where it was generating... It was making a folder called `Documents%20and%20Settings` and putting the generated documents in there instead of putting it in the `Documents and Settings` folder. Thanks for your help though :)